# General Form of Reflections and Glide Reflections

Tags: matrices, geometry, isometry

I am reading a set of notes about isometries of the plane. The section about reflections and glide reflections says that the general form for these isometries is:
$$x'=x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha+h$$
$$y'=x\sin\alpha-y\cos\alpha+k$$
But, the notes don't given any explanation of what $\alpha$, $h$, and $k$ are. These equations seem similar to a rotation, with some sign changes, but I'm not seeing how they are related. If anyone can help that would be wonderful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A reflection across a line through the origin making an angle of $\alpha/2$ with the horizontal axis is given by
$$ \begin{align*} x' = x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha \\y'=x \sin\alpha - y \cos\alpha\end{align*}$$

You can check this by verifying that the basis vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are mapped to their reflected selves: a reflection, being linear, is entirely determined by where the basis vectors are sent.

Then, the transformation

$$ \begin{align*} x' = x + h\\y'=y + k\end{align*}$$

where $h,k$ are real numbers, is simply a translation.

Since a glide reflection can be expressed as a reflection across a line through the origin followed by a translation, the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

The equations that you write actually define the composition of three isometries of the plane:

1. A rotation around the origin by an angle $\alpha$
2. A reflection about the rotated $X$-axis (flip the $y'$ coordinate)
3. A translation over a vector $(h,k).$

Answer (score 0):

A glide reflection is defined as reflection in a line plus a translation along that line.

Let $l$ be the line passing through $P_0(x_0,y_0)$ with direction vector $v=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Then, a glide reflection in $l$ is
$$P'=2((P-P_0)\cdot v)v+2P_0-P\color{red}{+}cv$$
Explicitly,
$$x'=\cos\alpha\,x+\sin\alpha\,y+h$$
$$y'=\sin\alpha\,x-\cos\alpha\,y+k$$
where
$$\small h=2x_0\sin^2\theta-2y_0\cos\theta\sin\theta +c\cos\theta$$
$$\small k=-2x_0\sin\theta\cos\theta+2y_0\cos^2\theta +c\sin\theta$$
and $\alpha=2\theta.$